# Use picture as a map on Android

Tags: android, images, maps

I have a picture of a map on my Android phone. I am looking for an app that can show my current location and direction overlaid on it.

The picture shows some local features that are not available in Google Maps or its alternatives. At the moment I have to switch between the image viewer and the map app, which is a bit cumbersome. I would prefer to add geospatial information to the picture by training it at a few known locations or overlaying it on top of Google Maps, and then use this information to show my current location right on the picture.

(Unfortunately all the terms I can use to describe such software are so generic that I get lots of unrelated results, which makes searching quite uneffective.)

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest that it would be worth the effort to add the missing features from the photo of the map as markers in your Google Maps MyMaps, possibly with the photo sections for those features attached.

The [google help](https://support.google.com/mymaps/#topic=3024924) on my maps is quite easy to follow and this would give you the extra data quite simply.

Answer (score 1):

**[Locus Maps](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=menion.android.locus)** can do that. There's a step-by-step guide showing how to be found in its knowledge base: [How to convert IMG maps to SQL](http://docs.locusmap.eu/doku.php?id=manual:advanced:convert_img_to_sql). The so converted image then can be used like any other map source: the app will show your position on it, and you will see "what's near to you".

I haven't used this specific feature yet, but *Locus Maps* is my favorite navigation app. I e.g. use POIs from self-created `.kml` overlays as "travel guides" (full featured with images etc, all available offline), and more. Take a look at my [Locus Maps Resources](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/resources_locus) for further hints.